# Is there any way for VBA (in Office 2011 for Mac) to run an AppleScript?

Tags: vba, macos, excel, applescript

This question has been asked before, but the suggested answers(to "VBA Shell function in Office 2011 for Mac") don't seem to work.

My Applescript, Run_Script.scpt, creates a small txt file. It runs perfectly in the editor. It also runs perfectly when compiled as an app and double-clicked on the desktop.

I need to invoke it from a VBA procedure. I have tried these:

```
Sub sub_scripttest()

Dim i As Integer
Dim result_long As Long
Dim result_str As String

'//==  the original question was this:
result_str = Shell("Macintosh HD:Applications:Run_Script.app", vbNormalFocus)
result_str = Shell("Macintosh HD/Applications/Run_Script.app", vbNormalFocus)
'//== gives a modal dialog box:  "Runtime error 53: File not found"

'//==  the suggested solution was this:
result_str = MacScript("do shell script ""Macintosh HD:Applications:Run_Script.app""")
result_str = MacScript("do shell script ""Macintosh HD/Applications/Run_Script.app""")
'//== gives a modal dialog box: "Runtime error 5: Invalid Procedure call or Argument"

'//==  another suggested solution was this:
result_long = system("Macintosh HD:Applications:Run_Script.app")
result_long = system("Macintosh HD/Applications/Run_Script.app")
'//==  appears to run, but returns   result_long=32512,   which is not a successful termination code.
'//==  also the desktop shows that the script did not run. The txt file was not created.

'//==  I even tried:
result_str = AppleScriptTask("Run_Script.scpt", "my_command", "")
'//==  and got: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined."

End Sub
```

I have OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. I am running Office 2011 for Mac. Excel has been updated to 14.7.2

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On ElCapitain with Excel 2011 (14.0.0) the 2 following macro are running.
You must adjust the path to your drive / users / script file.

Calling a script in VBA macro:

```
s = "run script (""ElCapitain:Users:imac27:Desktop:Test_Script.scpt"" as alias)"
Temp = MacScript(s)
```

Calling an app in VBA macro:

```
s = "run script (""ElCapitain:Users:imac27:Desktop:Test_App.app"" as alias)"
Temp = MacScript(s)
```